# Visual Studio 2015 Community - Immediate Window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I learnt quite a lot about the Immediate Window but I still have some questions that I cant seem to find any answer for.

1. How do I write multiple lines of code in the Immediate Window ? For example my code has the variable heap which is the boost::fibonacci heap and I want to see all its nodes.

   ```
   for (auto it = heap.begin(); it != heap.end(); it++)
       cout << it->a << " " << it->b << " " << it->distance;
   ```
2. How do I create and assign new variables ? For example, suppose my heap is of type `vector<int> heap;`
   But typing `vector<int> a = heap;` gives me the error message `identifier "vector<int>" is undefined`

If the immediate window was not meant to provide such support, are there any other alternatives within visual studio ? It would be nice if the syntax is similar to C++.

Comment: Not meant for this, no alternative.  REPL is a feature of an interpreted language, C++ is as opposite of such a language as you could imagine.  Just write a little program with the Win32 Console Application project template.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a compiled language, not an interpreted language. The Immediate Window appears to blur the distinction, but as you note it's limited. New variables, such as `auto it =` or `vector<int> heap =` are too complex. The Immediate Window is using the expression evaluation functionality in the IDE, but what you'd need are definitions.